# symfony 1.4 and php switch case

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1

In my database, i have a column which enum...column_name = enum('column1',column2','column3')
and in my action,

```
public function executeView_collection_details(sfWebRequest $r) {
    $collection = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Collections')->findOneById($r->getParameter('id'));
    $data = array();
    $this->setLayout(false);
    switch($collection->mode_of_payment) {
        case 'Column1':
            $obj = $collection->Column1;
            $data = array(
                    //.....
            );
            break;
        case 'Column2':
            $obj = $collection->Column2;
            $data = array(
                    //.......
            );
            break;
        case 'Column3':
            $obj = $collection->Column3[0];
            $data = array(
                    //.....
            );
            break;
    }

    $this->data = $data;
}
```

i added another column name term int(4).i dont want to add as an enum in mysql since the user will add them manually in form,what i mean is the value for this column will be added by the user.This column values represent number of days of payment(40,60,90...days)My question is, is it possible to add switch statement in the action for this column(term)?I want to display only number of rows for each value, e.g 40 days will print a table with fixed 40 number of rows.And I tried foreach statement but failed.I tried googling for some examples around the internet found no one..

Comment: Are you saying you need an HTML table with 40,60,90 rows in it based on the value of the column `term`? Assuming this is correct, a for statement would be the most logical way to create a table with that number of rows.

Comment: @Jester yes, I need an HTML table with 40,60,90 rows based on the column value(term).I can display a table using a foreach statement.But what I want is a fixed number of rows for each column value,since there is a date column in that table,I want to display some strings like "no payment for this date" if their is no payment received on certain dates.I will try a for statement tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Instead of switch, why don't you go to each field with getFieldNames() symfony native function?

```
$fn = TablePeer::getFieldNames();
$lists = TablePeer::doSelect($c);
$a = array();
$data = array();
$v = 0;         
foreach($lists as $list){               
    foreach($fn as $f){
        $function = "get$f";
        $a[$f] = $list->$function();
    }
    $data[$v] = $a;
    $v++;
}
return $data;
```

replace TablePeer with your Table name Peer.